# ffmpeg created m3u8 file can't be played by VLC

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, http-live-streaming

I used command as below to convert m4v file to m3u8/ts files,

```
ffmpeg -i IMG_0048.m4v -codec: copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls IMG_0048.m3u8
```

but VLC can't play that m3u8 file, after I deleted lines as below, VLC can play the same m3u8 file, can you tell me why?

```
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
```

Comment: what does the VLC log say?

Comment: `-- logger module started --
main: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
main: playlist is empty
adaptive error: Failed to create demuxer 00000000 Unknown
adaptive error: Failed to create demuxer 00000000 Unknown
adaptive error: Failed to create demuxer 00000000 Unknown
-- logger module stopped --
`

Comment: Have same problem